# Cmder Guest Windows 10, VirtualBox, See Available Drives is not working

Tags: windows-10, command-line, virtualbox, cmder, clink

I want to use **cmder** in my **VirtualBox Guest**, **Windows 10 Enterprise** version.

First I used **clink**, And was working properly, but using **cmder**, is not showing the drives like **clink**.

Here the output:

[image]

How solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't run "Admin" prompt.
You may easily see the same behavior if you run "Command prompt (administrator)" from Explorer.

Comment: I can't change Drive like Administrator?

Comment: Is there some alternative?

Comment: Administrator is "another user", so you don't see mapped drives. I don't see the reason to access remote drive under elevated account, but if you **really** need it, just access your remote files via network path or use "net map" to map another drive.